# return type of main in java

Tags: java

I like to know why only void return type for main method in java.

```
public static void main(String [] args)
```

Why there is no other return types other than void for main method.

Thanks

Comment: This is similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2431123/where-and-why-jvm-checks-that-the-return-type-of-entry-method-mainstring-args/2431145#2431145

Answer (score 28):

The short answer is: Because that's what the [language specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/execution.html#12.1.4) says.

In today's commonly used operating systems (Windows and Unix families), the only "return value" from a process is an [exit status](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status), which is a small number (usually 8-bit). This value can be returned from a Java program using the [`System.exit(int)`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#exit(int)) method:

> `public static void exit(int status)`
>
> Terminates the currently running Java Virtual Machine. The argument serves as a status code; by convention, a nonzero status code indicates abnormal termination.

Answer (score 24):

What were you expecting to return?

In C you typically return an `int` exit code. However, in a multithreaded system this doesn't make much sense. Typically a Java program will start a number of threads. The main thread will often return more or less immediately.

`System.exit` can be used to exit with a specific exit code.

Comment: +1 for the explanation that when main finishes, the program itself might not

Answer (score 2):

It seems like an arbitrary decision, probably considering that not all operating systems are unixy in the sense that they allow a program to return an exit code.

Java could have been specified like C with an `int` return code from `main`. Multi-threading does not matter because there is only one thread that originally starts main and its return value could be the one to be returned to the OS by the JVM, regardless of when the other threads return and what they do.

This is far-fetched but if someone built a JVM that can run multiple Java programs each with its own `main`, it could be designed to return the value returned by the last `main` to be invoked.

The most reasonable rationale is that the JVM itself may need to return an exit code for reasons of its own, however, this rationale is belied by the provision of `System.exit(int)` which exactly overrides the JVM's return code. Given this, there is no reason to similarly allow `main` to return an `int` too, just as if the last thing that `main` did was `System.exit(n)`

All in all, sounds like an arbitrary decision.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, because there is nothing to return values to.  Mainstream operating systems (e.g. Windows, UNIX, Linux, etc) do not allow commands to "return" values.  (Though arguably, the exit code is a return value, but it is restricted to an integer and there are various OS-specific caveats; e.g. on how many of the bits can come from the application.)

Secondly, because Java does not allow you to overload methods that differ only on the return type.

Thirdly, as @Tom points out, if the `exit code` was the return value of `main`, it would be difficult to deal with other threads calling `System.exit(rc)`.

Answer (score 0):

Java specifies that an application entry point must be `public static`, named `main`, returns `void`, and takes a `String[]` as a parameter. This is just the way it is.

That said, you *can* technically define a `main` method that doesn't meet those criterias, but *they won't be a valid application entry point*.

```
public class MainMain {
    public static void main(String args[]) { // application entry point
        System.out.println(main());
    }
    private static String main() {           // just a method named main
        return "Hello world!";
    }
}
```

You should probably reserve `main` only for valid Java application entry points, but there's nothing preventing you from writing a code like the above.

Answer (score 0):

Because you run main from JVM `Hello.main`, we can't return value to JVM. It simply gives run time exception.

Answer (score 0):

A reasonable middle way (between having a void signature, but also needing to return a value to the OS) to me then seems to be: To throw a Runtime exception in main for all return values that correspond to an error, with an appropriate message in that exception.

Of course, this helps only to differentiate between error and non-error exits at the OS level (say, a shell script etc.) but in many cases, this is actually all that is needed, and probably the most common use of these environment return values; either run or don't run the next command if this command fails.