# Why java's main method should not have a return value?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where and why JVM checks that the return type of entry method main(String args[]) is void and not anything else?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2431123/where-and-why-jvm-checks-that-the-return-type-of-entry-method-mainstring-args)
>   [return type of main in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441036/return-type-of-main-in-java)

After consulting these two questions [What's the meaning of the return value of int main(), and how to display it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13205941/whats-the-meaning-of-the-return-value-of-int-main-and-how-to-display-it) & [What should main() return in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-c), I come up with another question:

**Why Java program's main method should return void, but C/C++ program's main function should return int?**

Comment: Simply put, a Java program does not end because the `main` method (running on the main thread) ends. It ends **when all threads end**. Therefore there is no meaning to the return value of `main`.

Answer (score 2):

Java specification:

> The method main must be declared `public`, `static`, and `void`. It must accept a single argument that is an array of strings.

And further:

> A program terminates all its activity and exits when one of two things happens:
>
> - All the threads that are not daemon threads terminate.
> - Some thread invokes the exit method of class `Runtime` or class `System` and the exit operation is not forbidden by the security manager.

As you can see main return type might be meanless due to the exit of other threads.

Comment: The question is about WHY, but not WHAT.

Comment: @UniMouS: because that's how it is defined.